# How to tell if iisreset was successful

Tags: powershell, iis, remote-access

I'm working on a script that will automatically remove a Web Server from our load balancer pool, attempt an iisreset, and then put it back in.  The only trouble is, I don't know how to have the script detect whether or not the iisreset was successful, and I don't want to have the Web Server reinstated to the pool if the reset didn't work.

Is there a way for it to return a boolean value or failure message that I can use to then proceed to take other actions?  In code all I'm doing is

```
 Invoke-Command $Node {iisreset} -Credential $cred
```

But I don't know how to have it tell if that worked or not.  Anyone run into something similar?

Answer (score 3):

You can check the `$global:LastExitCode` variable:

```
if ($global:LastExitCode -ne 0)
{
    Write-Host "ERROR
}
```

Comment: sadly this doesn't seem to work.  it does not seem to return an exit code such as that

Answer (score 0):

Do a wget/telnet to the site and check the response.